# How can I add image dynamically with Vite and React from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a data JSON file in my assets folder, in a folder called data.
The data contains an array with objects on the following structure:

```
 {
    "id": 10,
    "company": "The Air Filter Company",
    "logo": "../images/the-air-filter-company.svg",
    "new": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Front-end Dev"
  }
```

The folder structure is:
SRC directory:

```
├───assets
│   ├───data
│   └───images
├───components
│   ├───CardWrapper
│   ├───Header
│   └───Main
└───styles
```

And the images are in the next folder.

Here are my steps:

1. Imported the array, and map over the elements, passing over the company object:

```
   import jobs from '../../assets/data/data.json';

   return (
     <section className={styles.mainWrapper}>
       {
           jobs?.map((item, index) => (
               <CardWrapper key={index} company={item} />
           ))
       }
     </section>
   )
```

2. Rendered the component and pass to the company prop `logo`.

```
const CardWrapper = ({ company }) => {


    return (
        <figure className={styles.figureJobCard}>
            <img src={company.logo} alt='company svg' width={70} height={70} /> 

....REST OF THE COMPONENT
```

[image]

***The issue here is that I don't get any error. I dont get the image rendered, nothing is in my console, in the networking tab I ahve status 304 (Unchanged....)***

I use Vite with react.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that your data object should be like this :

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "company": "The Air Filter Company",
    "logo": "images/the-air-filter-company.svg",
    "new": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Front-end Dev"
}
```

And where you use the logo property you should use it like this.
if you are in file : `src/components/CardWrapper/index.jsx` you should

```
const CardWrapper = ({ company }) => {
    const pathToAsset = '../../assets/'

    return (
        <figure className={styles.figureJobCard}>
            <img src={`${pathToAsset}${company.logo}`} alt='company svg' width={70} height={70} /> 

....REST OF THE COMPONENT
```

because you component CardWrapper doesn't know the path the images.
You can start by this answer and then once you want to improve your load times think about dynamic imports.